# Вопрос по поводу GET AND SET

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Есть класс Trip значение которое прилетает в объект DataOfBith (тип string)
как мне сделать так чтоб он его менял на DateOnly

```
 public partial class Client
    {
        public Client()
        {
            Auths = new HashSet<Auth>();
            Trips = new HashSet<Trip>();
            Wallets = new HashSet<Wallet>();
        }
        public int IdClient { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string MiddleName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string NumberDriver { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Passport { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Number { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateOnly DataOfBith {get; set;}
```

Вот ошибка из-за которой я задал этот вопрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в базе в каком формате поле, string? Тогда что вы хотите? Сохраняйте в базу как дату, а не как строку, тогда будет прозрачно работать.

Comment: В базе данных date only

Comment: Мне надо запарсить значение которое приходит в trip

Comment: Тип базы и версию EF укажите

Comment: Postre sql ef последний версии для postgresql

Comment: Последней версии - это EF 6?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Comment: Как я думаю надо что то поменять в get и set

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69146748/12888024

Comment: Мне приходит строка на сервер а в таблице у меня тип dateonly поэтому мне нужно конвертировать из строки в dateonly где стоят get and set

Comment: Что за строка? Json? Десереализуйте сразу дату, оно само распарсит.

Comment: Можно ли get and set поменять так что из string(что ему приходит ) он парсил в dateonly

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136701/discussion-between-nikita-and-aepot).